# rust mongodb driver DateTime

Tags: mongodb, rust

i just want to do a sum for `mongodb::bson::DateTime::now()`, in my code, i should find one document by filtering created_at field, i did this like below :

```
    let r = collection.find_one(
            doc! {
                "device_id": imei.split("/").collect::<Vec<&str>>()[2],
                "created_at": doc!{
                    "$gte": DateTime::now() + 6
                }
            },
            None).unwrap();
```

but i cant compile the code and get the following error:

```
 cannot add `{integer}` to `mongodb::bson::DateTime`
```

so what is the proper way of doing this? i cant find `TimeDelta` or something similar,
i am using [`this`](https://docs.rs/crate/mongodb/latest) driver
thank you.

Comment: it's may be app late, but what is the unit of the "6" ? do you want to add 6 seconds, minutes, hours or days ?

Comment: @LaabidiRaissi hi, it was `hours`, i changed my approach and solve the problem, but if you know the way to add hours or month or ... to DateTime objects, i will be glad to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

To be able to add like that you need to implement the trait Add for DateTime.
A simple (but may be not the most optimised ?) way is:

```
DateTime::from_millis(DateTime::now().timestamp_millis() + 6 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
```

It gets the current time in milliseconds and add to it 6 hours of millisecond.